# newbie, changing foreground color in visual studio

Tags: c#, console, textcolor

i've been doing one of the tutorial and i've messed up the console application foreground color. This is how original code supposed to look, but i monkeyed around and exit half way thru, no it dark magenta color on both C# and Python Projects, really hard to read =(((

> ```
>         // Preserve current console text color;
>         ConsoleColor oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
>
>         // Change console text color
>         Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
>         Console.WriteLine("Test Color");        
>
>         // Cleaning up 
>         Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor;
> ```

i've tried changing it with this, but what seemed to do is change the console color, when i Debug in Python project, but at the same time when i do No Debag of the same project in Python it still brings it back.

> Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
>               Console.WriteLine("Test Color");

i've tried do it it various orders, and checking it by creating new projects but nothing helped =(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really understanding here, but if you need magenta, can't you just change:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.WriteLine("Test Color")
```

to

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
        Console.WriteLine("Test Color")
```

if you want magenta.